# KDE's Dolphin Can't See Connected devices such as Nikon, Canon Cameras

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I have noticed this problem across all distros including Kubuntu and openSUSE. Many times my Nikon D 7000 and Canon HF 11 are not seen or mounted by Dolphin. When I connect the Cameras I don't get any notification in the tray which otherwise shows connected device. Ironically when I open Nautilus then I can clearly see the cameras mounted.

I also have a request that what these devices don't appear on Dolphin's side panel automatically. It makes life easier for a users.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/956806/+attachment/2879913/+files/dolphin.png

Answer (score 0):

**KDE device notifier**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/DeviceNotifier

> The Device Notifier is used for handling pluggable devices such as USB
>   pendrives (also called flash drives or thumb drives), digital cameras,
>   external USB hard drives, etc.

The device notifier notifies and mounts only the devices that have the correct information. That is, instructions what to do with the device.

KDE System Settings > Device Actions

**Rule of thumb: requests or bugs go to the...**

- Kubuntu/KDE packaging wishes or packaging bugs to the launchpad.
- KDE wishes or bugs to the KDE bugs: https://bugs.kde.org/

Searching with the Nikon: https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Nikon

**What have you tried ?**

- Have you tried with the KDE System Settings > Digital Camera ?
- Do you have the digiKam installed ?

Comment: @It works fine under openSUSE 12.1. No I don't have digiKam installed. I don't need digiKam. Yes, tried Digital Camera setting, selected D7000 but nothing happened.

Comment: Luckily (?) this bug seems to catch the developers attention: http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/03/26/%23kubuntu-devel.html .  22:37 onward.